# Calculate the sum of elements in a matrix efficiently

Tags: algorithm, matrix

In an interview I was asked if I was given an n*m matrix how to calculate the sum of the values in a given sub-matrix (defined by top-left, bottom-right coordinates).

I was told I could pre-process the matrix.

I was told the matrix could be massive and so could the sub-matrix so the algo had to be efficient.  I stumbled a bit and wasn't told the best answer.

Anyone have a good answer?

Comment: is the matrix known to be sparse?

Comment: @Moron a quadtree where each node contains the sum of its children would support relatively easy update, but not nearly as easy summing as the simple answer from Alan.

Comment: @Moron: The question *begins* with "In an interview I was asked". So no, not homework, unless there exist situations where homework somehow consists of interviews...

Comment: Matrix can be sparse or dense, he mentioned that it needs work for any case.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is what Summed Area Tables are for.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table

Your "preprocessing" step is to build a new matrix of the same size, where each entry is the sum of the sub-matrix to the upper-left of that entry.  Any arbitrary sub-matrix sum can be calculated by looking up and mixing only 4 entries in the SAT.

**EDIT:** Here's an example.

For the initial matrix

```
0 1 4
2 3 2
1 2 7
```

The SAT is

```
0 1 5
2 6 12
3 9 22
```

The SAT is obtained using  S(x,y) = a(x,y) + S(x-1,y) + S(x,y-1) - S(x-1,y-1),

where S is the SAT matrix and a is the initial matrix .

If you want the sum of the lower-right 2x2 sub-matrix, the answer would be 22 + 0 - 3 - 5 = 14.  Which is obviously the same as 3 + 2 + 2 + 7.  Regardless of the size of the matrix, the sum of a sub matrix can be found in 4 lookups and 3 arithmetic ops. Building the SAT is O(n), similarly requiring only 4 lookups and 3 math ops per cell.

Comment: +1 For the right answer. I never heard of that before. I would have blurted out something with a quadtree, but this is much better. It's interview trivia unless they wanted someone who knew (or claimed to know) a particular algorithm that uses it.

Comment: Thanks Alan! I've never heard of a Summed Area Table and I've been programming for 18 years.  I slept/drank through University though (my bad).

Comment: I have been *using* this idea for several years and never heard of the name "summed area tables" either – the poorly written Wikipedia article suggests that it's a name specific to the computer vision/graphics field. The idea itself is fairly natural to someone who's familiar with dynamic programming, though – too natural to deserve a name, perhaps.

Comment: I marked this "not answered" as I tried applying the algo defined in the SAT wiki link above to apandit's example matrix below:

 0 1 4 
 2 3 2
 1 2 7

Comment: See my updated answer if you don't believe this works.  This is pretty simple intro-to-algorithms stuff here.

Comment: That's why the algorithm section of StackOverflow is definitely the most interesting. You learn new concepts everyday.. only wish I could remember them.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Your comment is fair, but the bit about dynamic programming just doesn't make any sense. Anyway, could you share what you have been using this algorithm for?

Comment: @Tymek: There are dozens of USACO problems and IOI problems (not to mention problems from other olympiads), from the last 10+ years, that use the idea of keeping a cumulative sum (which is all this is). It's a fairly standard DP trick. Off the top of my head, see e.g. the [solution](http://ioinformatics.org/locations/ioi04/contest/day1/artemis-sol.pdf) (2) to [Artemis from IOI 2004](http://ioinformatics.org/locations/ioi04/contest/day1/artemis.pdf).

Comment: S(x,y) = a(x,y) + S(x-1,y) + S(x,y-1) - S(x-1,y-1) There's a subtraction involved because when we add S[i][j-1] and S[i-1][j], the S[i-1][j-1] is added two times as S[i-1][j-1] is common in both S[i][j-1] and S[i-1][j]...

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by Dynamic programming. Create matrix dp with size n*m. 
And for each i, j where

```
1 <= i <= n , 1 <= j <= m 
dp[i][j] will be : 

dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j] + dp[i][j - 1] - dp[i - 1][j - 1] + values[i][j]
```

And for each query we have lx, rx, ly, ry where lx and rx are top-left coordinates, ly and ry bottom-right coordinates of sub-matrix.

```
1 ≤ lxi ≤ rx ≤ n, 1 ≤ ly ≤ ry ≤ m

sum = dp[rx][ry]  - dp[lx - 1][ry] - dp[rx][ly - 1] + dp[lx-1][ly - 1]
```

Look at picture to understand how algorithm works.

```
OD = dp[rx][ry], OB = dp[lx - 1][ry], OC = dp[rx][ly - 1], OA = dp[lx - 1][ly - 1]
```

[image]

Comment: This is the best way this algorithm can be illustrated! Thanks! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

Create a new matrix where entry `(i,j)` is the sum of elements in the original matrix that have lower or equal `i` and `j`. Then, to find the sum of the elements in the submatrix, you can just use a constant number of basic operations using the corners of the submatrix of your sum matrix.

In particular, find the corners top_left, bottom_left, top_right and bottom_right of your sum matrix, where the first three are just outside the submatrix and bottom_right is just inside. Then, your sum will be

```
bottom_right + top_left - bottom_left - bottom_right
```

Comment: In that case, my misunderstanding lies with what is defined as "preprocessing". You still require the same number of additions, no matter what. I understand when this approach can be useful, but the question provided no further information about the problem context.

Comment: There wasn't really a context, just a requirement that the addition be faster than simply looping and adding.  Preprocessing was suggested but not to the extent that extreme amounts of memory or storage are used (e.g. pre-summing every possible matrix and storing it in an x/y index).

Answer (score 1):

Below is a sample implementation in C using Summed Area Tables concept as explained in one of the answers above.

Python implementation for the same can be found at below link -
http://www.ardendertat.com/2011/09/20/programming-interview-questions-2-matrix-region-sum/

```
#include<stdio.h>

int pre[3][3];

int arr[3][3] = {
                {0,1,4},
                {2,3,2},
                {1,2,7}
                };

void preprocess()
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            if(i>0 && j>0)
            {
                 pre[i][j] = arr[i][j] + pre[i-1][j] + pre[i][j-1] - pre[i-1][j-1];
            }
            else if(i>0 && j==0)
            {
                pre[i][j] = arr[i][j] + pre[i-1][j];
            }
            else if(j>0 && i==0)
            {
                pre[i][j] = arr[i][j] + pre[i][j-1];
            }
            else
            {
                pre[i][j] = arr[i][j];
            }                    
        }
    }
}

int subsum(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    preprocess();

    int ans = pre[x2][y2] - pre[x1-1][y2] - pre[x2][y1-1] + pre[x1-1][y1-1];
    return ans;
}

int main()
{            
    printf("%d\n",subsum(1,1,2,2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what doses this do ? subsum(1,1,2,2)); what are those numbers? 1 , 1 , 2 ,2 ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You always have to go through each element in the submatrix to do the addition and this is the simplest way.

*note that the following code may not compile but it's right in pseudocode

```
struct Coords{
    int x,y;
}

int SumSubMatrix(Coords topleft, Coords bottomright, int** matrix){
    int localsum = 0;
    for( int i = topleft.x; i <= bottomright.x; i++ ){
        for(int j = topleft.y; j <= bottomright.y; j++){
            localsum += matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return localsum;
}
```

Edit: An alternative pre-processing method is to create another matrix from the original containing the row or column sums. Here's an example:
Original:

```
0 1 4 
2 3 2
1 2 7
```

Row Matrix:

```
0 1 5
2 5 7
1 3 10
```

Column Matrix:

```
0 1 4
2 4 6
3 6 13
```

Now, just take the endpoint x values and subtract the start point values, like so (for rows based):

```
for( int i = topleft.y; i >= bottomright.y; i++ ){
    localsum += matrix2[bottomright.x][i] - matrix2[topleft.x][i];
}
```

Now, it's either O( n ) or O( m )