# Is there a faster way to calculate sum of submatrix?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, submatrix

I have to caluclate sum from several submatrixes from square matrix. I have an input of that format:

```
8 8 // matrix is 8 x 8 and there are going to be 8 submatrixes
-5 -4 -6 -2 1 -8 6 -1 //first row of the matrix
-9 7 -3 -7 2 0 -6 -2  // second row of the matrix etc.
6 -8 2 6 -7 0 3 -5
-1 3 9 4 -7 0 -5 -3
-8 0 0 -6 -5 -7 -7 0
2 7 6 2 -6 6 5 0
-1 -7 8 -7 6 7 -2 1
-8 -3 -5 2 -5 4 -1 -2
0 2 3 6  //upperRow, leftColumn, lowerRow, rightColumn of submatrix
2 6 4 6
0 7 1 7
7 4 7 4
1 7 7 7
2 7 6 7
4 5 6 5
6 2 7 5
```

I need to calculate totals(inter alia) from all submatrixes. My code works just fine(compiles, runs, gives right results), but my method `public static int total(int[][] M, int upperRow, int leftColumn, int lowerRow, int rightColumn)` kills all the performance(I measured it). To be exact the loops inside kills it.

Is there a faster way(more efficient) to calulculate totals of submatrixes?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Main {

    public static void display(int[][] a2d) {
        for (int[] a : a2d) {
            for (int val : a) {
                System.out.print(val + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int total(int[][] M, int upperRow, int leftColumn, int lowerRow, int rightColumn) {
        int rows = lowerRow - upperRow + 1;
        int cols = rightColumn - leftColumn + 1;
        int sum = 0;
        int columnToCopyFrom = leftColumn;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                sum += M[upperRow][columnToCopyFrom];
                columnToCopyFrom++;
            }
            columnToCopyFrom = leftColumn;
            upperRow++;
        }
        return sum;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input3"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] firstLine = br.readLine().split(" ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[0]);
        int k = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[1]);
        int[][] M = new int[n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String[] rowContents = br.readLine().split(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < rowContents.length; j++) {
                M[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(rowContents[j]);
            }
        }

        int avgSum = 0;
        int total;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            String[] rowContents = br.readLine().split(" ");
            int upperRow = Integer.parseInt(rowContents[0]);
            int leftColumn = Integer.parseInt(rowContents[1]);
            int lowerRow = Integer.parseInt(rowContents[2]);
            int rightColumn = Integer.parseInt(rowContents[3]);
            total = total(M, upperRow, leftColumn, lowerRow, rightColumn);
            //srednia
            avgSum += total;
            //klasy abstrakcji
            if (!map.containsKey(total)) {
                map.put(total, 1);
            } else {
                map.put(total, map.get(total) + 1);
            }
            //display(cutOut);
        }
        int maxCount = 0;
        int maxAbstractionClass = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        ArrayList<Entry> list = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() > maxCount || (entry.getValue() == maxCount && entry.getKey() > maxAbstractionClass)) {
                maxAbstractionClass = entry.getKey();
                maxCount = entry.getValue();
            }

        }
        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if(maxCount==entry.getValue()){
            list.add(entry);
        }
        }
        System.out.print(map.size() + " " + list.size() + " " + avgSum / k);

    }
}
```

---

I shaved few milisecond by remembering totals in the `HashMap`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Main {
    public static HashMap<FourNumbers, Integer> mapOfTotals = new HashMap<FourNumbers, Integer>();
    public static void display(int[][] a2d) {
        for (int[] a : a2d) {
            for (int val : a) {
                System.out.print(val + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int total(int[][] M, int upperRow, int leftColumn, int lowerRow, int rightColumn) {
        FourNumbers fourNumbers = new FourNumbers(upperRow, leftColumn, lowerRow, rightColumn);
        if(mapOfTotals.containsKey(fourNumbers)){
            return mapOfTotals.get(fourNumbers);
        }
        int rows = lowerRow - upperRow + 1;
        int cols = rightColumn - leftColumn + 1;
        int sum = 0;
        int columnToCopyFrom = leftColumn;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                sum += M[upperRow][columnToCopyFrom];
                columnToCopyFrom++;
            }
            columnToCopyFrom = leftColumn;
            upperRow++;
        }
        mapOfTotals.put(fourNumbers, sum);
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input3"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] firstLine = br.readLine().split(" ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[0]);
        int k = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[1]);
        int[][] M = new int[n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String[] rowContents = br.readLine().split(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < rowContents.length; j++) {
                M[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(rowContents[j]);
            }
        }

        int avgSum = 0;
        int total;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();//KLUCZEM jest nazwa klasy abstrakcji(suma), wartoscia jest liczba wystapien tej klasy abstrakcji
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            String[] rowContents = br.readLine().split(" ");
            int upperRow = Integer.parseInt(rowContents[0]);
            int leftColumn = Integer.parseInt(rowContents[1]);
            int lowerRow = Integer.parseInt(rowContents[2]);
            int rightColumn = Integer.parseInt(rowContents[3]);
            total = total(M, upperRow, leftColumn, lowerRow, rightColumn);
            //srednia
            avgSum += total;
            //klasy abstrakcji
            if (!map.containsKey(total)) {
                map.put(total, 1);
            } else {
                map.put(total, map.get(total) + 1);
            }
            //display(cutOut);
        }
        int maxCount = 0;
        int maxAbstractionClass = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        ArrayList<Entry> list = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() > maxCount || (entry.getValue() == maxCount && entry.getKey() > maxAbstractionClass)) {
                maxAbstractionClass = entry.getKey();
                maxCount = entry.getValue();
            }

        }
        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (maxCount == entry.getValue()) {
                list.add(entry);
            }
        }
        System.out.print(map.size() + " " + list.size() + " " + avgSum / k);

    }
}

class FourNumbers {
    int upperRow, leftColumn, lowerRow, rightColumn;

    public FourNumbers(int upperRow, int leftColumn, int lowerRow, int rightColumn) {
        this.upperRow = upperRow;
        this.leftColumn = leftColumn;
        this.lowerRow = lowerRow;
        this.rightColumn = rightColumn;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + leftColumn;
        result = prime * result + lowerRow;
        result = prime * result + rightColumn;
        result = prime * result + upperRow;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        FourNumbers other = (FourNumbers) obj;
        if (leftColumn != other.leftColumn)
            return false;
        if (lowerRow != other.lowerRow)
            return false;
        if (rightColumn != other.rightColumn)
            return false;
        if (upperRow != other.upperRow)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the sum of elements in a matrix efficiently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277749/calculate-the-sum-of-elements-in-a-matrix-efficiently)

Comment: @PhamTrung No, no, no, there are c++ solutions, I need a Java solution.

Comment: You need a java solution, so you need to work on it your self. The algorithm stay the same. Implementation is easy when you understand the concept in my link.

Comment: @PhamTrung my submatrixes are not square.

Comment: I don't see any where mention that the algorithm is only applied to square. Have you even read the link?

Comment: @PhamTrung Yes, I did, but I don't understand this part`22 + 0 - 3 - 5 = 14` from highest voted answer, Why 0,3 and 5 are subtracted. What numbers I should subtract if I choose right lower 1 x 1 submatrix?  

EDIT: let me get through your answer. thank you.

Comment: Do you understand what is SAT? for example, s(2, 2) is the sum of submatrix (0, 0, 2, 2), and s(3, 4) is the sum of submatrix (0, 0, 3, 4). So, in the case we want to find the sum of submatrix (1, 1, 3, 4), we need to take `s(3, 4) - s(0, 4) - s(3, 0) + s(0, 0)`. Take a look at the wiki link, and draw those submatrices. Look at those overlapping areas, you will understand why.

Comment: @PhamTrung Ok, I think I get it. When I want to calculate `submatrix(upperRow, leftColumn, lowerRow, rightColumn)` I should calculate `s(upperRow, leftColumn, lowerRow, rightColumn) - s(0, rightColumn) - s(lowerRow, 0)  + s(upperRow, leftColumn)` ?

Comment: You're almost there, not correct yet, but I think you are very near, try different case, for example, (2, 3, 4, 5), using some drawing. Correct formula should be `s(lowerRow, rightColumn) - s(upperRow - 1, rightColumn) - s(lowerRow, leftColumn - 1) + s(upperRow - 1, leftColumn - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have to calculate all submatrices of lets say size 4x4 you do this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            sum += M[i][j];
        }
    }
    stored[0][0]=sum;
```

then for all subsequent matrices you add a column or row at the end and subtract the row or column that has left the submatrix from the front

```
            sum = stored[0][0];

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            sum -= M[0][j];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            sum -= M[j][0];
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            sum += M[4][j];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            sum += M[j][4];
        }
```

Also, this is redundant - you dont need to add extra variables just the variables of the loop suffice

```
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            sum += M[upperRow][columnToCopyFrom];
            columnToCopyFrom++;
        }
        columnToCopyFrom = leftColumn;
        upperRow++;
    }

   for (int i = upperRow; i <= loweRow; i++) {
        for (int j = leftColumn; j <= rightColumn; j++) {
            sum += M[i][j];
        }
    }
```